# Output from pyspark won't show up in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-emr

AWS newbie here, I'm trying to run a pyspark job on an EMR cluster, but I can't seem to figure out why my output won't save to the specified s3 bucket.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="appName")
    rdd = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5])
    rdd.saveAsTextFile("s3a://ouput-bucket/output")
    sc.stop()
```

I submit the job with the script

```
#!bin/bash
aws s3 cp $2 s3://bucket-with-script/script.py 

aws emr add-steps --cluster-id $1 \
--steps Type=spark,Name=appName,\
Args=[--deploy-mode,cluster,--master,yarn,\
--verbose,\
--conf,spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=False,\
--num-executors,5,\
--executor-cores,5,\
--executor-memory,2g,\
s3a://bucket-with-script/script.py,\]\
,ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

stderr:
https://paste.ee/p/OwSOj

EDIT: I don't know if this changes anything but I am doing all of this through an ec2 instance.

Comment: First, we can't see that log file. Secondly, `saveAsTextFile` should create a folder (s3 object) `out-file.csv` on your bucket where the saved output is under the folder `out-file.csv`

Comment: But shouldnt that give me some files under that name? Either way i removed the .csv and there was still nothing. Not quite sure about the correct formatting for logs, but I hope that means something to you.

Answer (score 0):

try saving one level down, e.g. s3a://bucket/dest/out.csv

there's always some "anomalies" with that root directory, on account of it being special: it's always there, even if you delete it, and similar.

Comment: Oh, you are on EMR. Switch to the (amazon closed source) s3:// URL

Comment: Unfortunately that did nothing either. Could It be something to do with the way I submit jobs? I go from an ubuntu ec2 instance, upload the script onto s3 then add the step, the steps gets marked as completed but nothing shows up. I'm assuming the problem is with this step, since if it was a permission problem it would have presented itself by now? I've also thrown admin rights everywhere, would that have any effect?

Comment: EMR is a closed box to me, I'm afraid. Why not try spark-standalone and write direct from your laptop: spark can commit work to s3 remote. Once its working locally, then worry about in-EMR deployments